# Escaped spaces does not work with "ls" when feeding to command

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

first time on here, I apologize if I missed anything.

I am currently writing a script that searches through each folder and looks for a `<filename>.vmdk` file, after of which I want to do `ls -lah` on this file.

Here is my current code for the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

parse_dir () {
    for file in ./**/*[A-Za-z][!-flat][!-thin].vmdk; do
    #echo "File Found: "${file//\ /\\\ }
    ls -lah "${file//\ /\\\ }"
    #vmkfstools -i "${file//\ /\\\ }" -d thin "${file%.vmdk}-thin.vmdk"
    #echo "New provisioned file: ${file%.vmdk}-thin.vmdk"
    done
}

parse_dir
```

This script outputs all of the matched files like this:
`ls: ./ABC\ Collector/ABC\ Collector.vmdk: No such file or directory`

HOWEVER! If I manually type in `ls -lah ./ABC\ Collector/ABC\ Collector.vmdk` this file exists just fine.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You are double-quoting the variable expansion `"${file//\ /\\\ }"` - if you escape spaces as well, that's like `ls -lah "./ABC\ Collector/ABC\ Collector.vmdk"`

Comment: @steeldriver make it an answer and I'll +1 it

Comment: @James the OP isn't parsing `ls`. Look at the code again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to escape the spaces when they're the result of an quoted expansion.

```
$ touch 'some file.txt'
$ ls -l some\ file.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 ilkkachu ilkkachu 0 Sep 17 01:03 some file.txt
$ f='some file.txt'
$ ls -l "$f"
-rw-r--r-- 1 ilkkachu ilkkachu 0 Sep 17 01:03 some file.txt
```

In fact, as you saw, it doesn't work. Quotes and escapes are only special before variable expansions, quotes that come as result of expansions aren't. Expanding a variable in the shell command line is not the same as just putting the variable contents literally in the same place in the command line. (It's not a macro processor, it's a programming language.)

```
$ s='foo\ bar'
$ printf ':%s\n' $s
:foo\
:bar
$ printf ':%s\n' "$s"
:foo\ bar
```

Without quotes, the value of `s` is split on whitespace (by the contents of `IFS`), with quotes, it isn't. In neither case does the backslash escape the space.

In a for loop like that, you could just do

```
for f in ./**/*.vmdk; do
    ls -l "$f"
done
```

Though note that `*[A-Za-z][!-flat][!-thin].vmdk` probably doesn't do what you mean, `[A-Za-z]` matches one character that is a letter, and `[!-flat]` matches any *one* character that isn't `-`, `f`, `l`, `a`, or `t`. That would e.g. include `abc.vmdk`, but not `bac.vmdk`.

Instead, use another condition to rule out the unwanted cases:

```
for file in ./**/*.vmdk; do
    case "$file" in
        *-flat.vmdk) continue;;
        *-thin.vmdk) continue;;
    esac
    echo "found: $file"
    ls -l "$file"
    new=${file%.vmdk}-thin.vmdk
    # vmkfstools -i "$file" -d thin "$new"
    # echo "New provisioned file: $new"
done
```

See:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373)
- https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting

Comment: +1 Thank you!! I have gone with the following
https://github.com/txj-xyz/Scripts/blob/master/Bash/convert-to-thin-vmdk.sh

Answer (score 1):

Spaces in filenames will hate you and you will hate them, especially when passing them around from filenames into globs into scripted shell commands.  Let `find` and `xargs` do the heavy lifting for you:

```
$  tree
.
+--- ABC Collector
|   +--- ABC Collector-flat.vmdk
|   +--- ABC Collector-thin.vmdk
|   +--- ABC Collector.vmdk
$  find . -type f -name '*.vmdk' -not -name '*-flat.vmdk' -not -name '*-thin.vmdk' -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lah
-rw-r--r--    1 myuser mygroup       0 Sep 16 14:29 ./ABC Collector/ABC Collector.vmdk
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I understand this now and how the structure of this works :) +1